# In swift, how do you add button using a for loop in stack view in scroll view?

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, uistackview

I have added two scroll views, and two vertical stack views inside them, respectively. The constraints have been set already. I have connect the two stack views as outlet collections in ViewController.swift. Suppose I have an array of strings, say

I wanted to add a few buttons (same as length of labels) in the top stack view using a for loop. How do I do this? And since the stack view is in scroll view, do I need to specify the distance between two buttons?

My code is below.

```
    @IBOutlet var topStackView: [UIStackView]!
    @IBOutlet var bottomStackView: [UIStackView]!
    @IBOutlet weak var enterItemTextField: UITextField!
    let labels = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        enterItemTextField.delegate = self

        var buttons = [UIButton()]
        for _ in 0..<labels.count {

            let button = UIButton(type: UIButton.ButtonType.system)
            # some operations on button
            buttons.append(button)
        }
        # what do I do here?

    }
```

The stackview has less freedom to adjust the locations. I have removed the stackview and am putting buttons on the scroll view directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need it after

```
buttons.append(button)
topStackView.addArrangedView(button)
```

---

BTW for single item you don't need a collection so to be

```
@IBOutlet var topStackView: UIStackView!
@IBOutlet var bottomStackView: UIStackView!
```

instead of

```
@IBOutlet var topStackView: [UIStackView]!
@IBOutlet var bottomStackView: [UIStackView]!
```

---

> Do I need to specify the distance between two buttons?

no you don't have to but you can do this

```
topStackView.spacing = 20
```